Calculate daily temperature and precipitation given a csv of lat/lon and dates
I have a csv with four columns: site ID, latitude, longitude, and a date. I need to calculate the average daily temperature and total daily precipitation for each site at each date. I am trying to use the package "daymetr".



site
lat
lon
date




d22002
35.1527
-84.0396
11/8/2017


d22002
35.1527
-84.0396
11/1/2017


d22066
36.4246
-84.4666
11/15/2017


d22065
35.2741
-81.5184
1/22/2017



All my dates fall during 2017, so I used the following code to extract data:
library(daymetr)

site_weather2017 <- download_daymet_batch(
  file_location = "templateforweatherdata.csv",
  start = 2017,
  end = 2017,
  internal = TRUE,
  force = FALSE,
  silent = FALSE,
  path = tempdir(),
  simplify = FALSE
)

Which gives me a daymetr object with 365 days of temp/precip data for each lat/lon location. How do I narrow it down to match just the date specified in each column?
I have tried this code:
finaldata <- list()

for( i in 1:length(site_weather2017)){
  site <- site_weather2017[[i]]
  site.dat <- site$data
  
  #add a column of mean daily temperature
  site.dat["tmean"] <- rowMeans(site.dat[,c("tmax..deg.c.","tmin..deg.c.")])
  
  #choose timespan of interest
  beginDate <- yday(as.Date(format="%m-%d-%Y"))
 # s.Date(alldata$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  
  #subset to only timespan of interest
  subSite <- subset(site.dat, yday %in% beginDate:beginDate)
  
  subSite['precip'] <- subSite$prcp..mm.day.
  
  #calculate mean daily temperature, and sum of precipitation
  finaldata[[i]] <- data.frame(site=site$site, meanTemp=mean(subSite$tmean), 
                               sumPrecip=base::sum(subSite$prcp..mm.day.))
}


But temp and precip show up as NaN.

library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(daymetr)

## read the sites data
sites <- read_csv("templateforweatherdata.csv", 
                  col_types = cols(date = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y")))

## we only need to download each site once, hence getting unique values
sites_unique <- sites %>% distinct(site, .keep_all = TRUE)
write.csv(sites_unique, "unique_templateforweatherdata.csv", row.names = F)

## using the unique site list for download
## we still will be processing the dates based on the original file
site_weather2017 <- download_daymet_batch(
  file_location = "unique_templateforweatherdata.csv",
  start = 2017,
  end = 2017,
  internal = TRUE,
  force = FALSE,
  silent = FALSE,
  path = tempdir(),
  simplify = FALSE
)
#> Downloading DAYMET data for: d22002 at 35.1527/-84.0396 latitude/longitude !
#> Done !
#> Downloading DAYMET data for: d22066 at 36.4246/-84.4666 latitude/longitude !
#> Done !
#> Downloading DAYMET data for: d22065 at 35.2741/-81.5184 latitude/longitude !
#> Done !

## creating an empty list to store the filtered data
site_weather2017_data <- list()

## looping over the downloaded data
for(i in seq_along(site_weather2017)) {
  
  ## getting desired dates for each site
  site_dates <- subset(sites, site == site_weather2017[[i]]$site,
                       select = date)$date
  
  ## data for each site
  site_weather2017[[i]]$data %>% 
    ## adding columns for the header of each daymetr object
    ## i.e. site name, tile, lat/long/alt, and
    ## ... adding a column for date
    mutate(site = site_weather2017[[i]]$site,
           tile = site_weather2017[[i]]$tile,
           latitude = site_weather2017[[i]]$latitude,
           longitude = site_weather2017[[i]]$longitude,
           altitude = site_weather2017[[i]]$altitude,
           date = as.Date(as.numeric(yday), origin = paste0(year, "-01-01")), 
           .before = 1) %>% 
    ## filtering for desired dates
    filter(date %in% site_dates) -> site_weather2017_data[[i]]
}

## binding the rows together for a final dataframe
bind_rows(site_weather2017_data)

#>     site  tile latitude longitude altitude       date year yday dayl..s.
#> 1 d22002 11208  35.1527  -84.0396      607 2017-11-01 2017  304 37960.51
#> 2 d22002 11208  35.1527  -84.0396      607 2017-11-08 2017  311 37193.35
#> 3 d22066 11388  36.4246  -84.4666      455 2017-11-15 2017  318 36175.83
#> 4 d22065 11210  35.2741  -81.5184      266 2017-01-22 2017   21 35987.47
#>   prcp..mm.day. srad..W.m.2. swe..kg.m.2. tmax..deg.c. tmin..deg.c. vp..Pa.
#> 1          0.00       361.07            0        19.01         0.26  622.54
#> 2         10.84        97.65            0        18.38        13.12 1508.59
#> 3          0.00       291.03            0        13.50         0.62  638.79
#> 4         12.31        76.66            0        13.61         9.88 1217.81

Created on 2024-07-14 with reprex v2.0.2

I cleared my environment and ran your code again and it worked beautifully thank you! It gives me 14 days for each with the date being listed out of 365. Do you know how to coerce a daymetr object into a dataframe with only the one date listed?

My data has ~340 sites, and each site needs 14 days of data. So the CSV looks like list of ~4000 rows and 4 columns. Since I need 14 dates for each site, the lat/lon/date is the same for 14 rows and only the date differs for each. Maybe this is where my code is getting confused?

@JElliott See my edited response. Initially I thought you want to get the data for dates between, not to get the data for each date (thinking you have 2 rows per site, with start and end date). Now, I changed it to filter for every date present in sites csv dataset, and store it in a separate list of dataframes (I also filtered the csv for unique site names to not download the same site multiple times). I have also added additional columns for info stored in the header of daymetr objects. At the end, I bind the list into a single dataframe as you requested. Hope this helps.
